# Online fingerprint authentication

Tags: php, linux, verification, fingerprint

The company has a web-based punch card application, but my boss wants to make employees punch in and out using their fingerprint rather than sharable passwords. Is there any free/open source/commercial SDKs that can be used? With a Java or ActiveX based embeddable component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered having barcodes tattooed on the employee's foreheads?

Comment: @Neil you can just import Java.Forehead.Barcode;

Comment: I sentence you and your boss to watch Mythbuster's "Crimes and Mythdemenors 2" (season 4) where they defeat a fingerprint scanner.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAfAVGES-Yc  Passwords may not be perfect, but at least you don't walk around stamping them on everything you touch.  And if it gets stolen, I can change my password.

Comment: Haha, very unfunny. If your are not going to help please keep your dull humor to yourselves.

Comment: @Moutaz I was serious.  Fingerprint auth is obfuscation at best.  It violates basic principles of cryptography.  The key should be secret, your fingerprint is not a secret, its just obfuscated; and if the key compromised it can be easily changed, but you can't change your fingerprints.

Icing on the cake: you carry this key for LIFE!  If you hand it to your current employer and they let it get out you compromise every other thing that wants to use fingerprint auth.  Like, say, your fancy, futuristic biometric loaded passport.

Comment: Moutaz, I agree with @Schwern about fingerprint authentication.  If you're going to use a fingerprint, then you need to add a second mode of authentication, like a PIN number.  The phrase to read up on is "multi factor authentication."

Comment: Nw, assuming that you have a PHB who insists, there are a number of commercial fingerprint mechanisms around, but you have to buy hardware to read fingerprints.  Once you do, the interfaces are usually not all that tough: they usually present a signature string or number.

Comment: By the way, by "punch card" do you mean "time card"?  As in "you punch in when you start work"?  If so, there are a number of commercial timeclocks around.  Google "cardless time clock" and you'll get several adverts and a bunch of links.

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I mean. He wants to link that with the existing web based HR system, i.e. must be developed in-house, and he is insisting it must run within a browser, and he doesn't want to use proprietary hardware???? See my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the tools i found were commercial products. But hopefully they lead you in the right direction you want to take.

- [Griaule fingerprint recognition software](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/page/en-us/index)
- [Universal Matching System Software Development Kits](http://www.123id.us/products_developer_cvtsdk.html)
- [OSS BioFoundry](http://www.biofoundry.com/products/biofoundryFreeTrial.html)

Answer (score 1):

Which fingerprint reader are you using?

1) Microsoft Fingerprint Reader (Formerly Digital Persona)
2) Eikon Reader
3) Other?

An easy solution is to take advantage of the automatic form-filling tools that come with either, and build a password system around that where the passwords are predefined 64+ byte long random blocks of data. Keep your web-based system but have a very minimal form that discourages entering the password client-side (through javascript), and explains that the user should touch the fingerprint scanner to punch in/out.

If possible, take each employee through the registration system by having them setup an auto-login with their fingerprint, having them look away and then privately entering the password without them watching.

Of course this is easily hacked by a tech-savy employee using a tool like asterisk key (on windows) or a dom explorer / debugger later but it should provide a minimum level of security and at the very least won't be as easily shared as your current system (which I gather is your goal).

Also, fingerprints don't really provide any type of security for a determined attack. Silly putty, superglue, and five minutes can reliably replicate any prints lying around. As long as you accept this issue you'll be OK.