# Login authentication using fingerprint in jsp page

Tags: java, fingerprint

I am a final year student, i am trying to provide higher level of security at web login time for clients. So, i am looking for fingerprint authentication. Which means, wherever client wants to login he/she has to login using his/her fingerprint. (Assuming client is using digital persona personal fingerprint reader for finger scan). So, is it possible...? if it is, then how..?? Because, i googled my problem , but didn't get helpful material to implement on my project.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your fingerprint reader specifically has support for this functionality, chances are that it's not possible. As a general rule, web pages are intentionally prevented from having direct access to hardware.

Also, see the comments on [Online fingerprint authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791677/online-fingerprint-authentication) for some reasons why fingerprint authentication may not be quite so awesome as it sounds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... but, i have already gone through...it's no use.. i was trying to install on my computer, then an error occurred, (i forgot error message). if you know.. how to use this sdk... then provide me steps. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the fingerprint scanner from Java in the browser security context, then you could use Digital Persona's [drivers](http://www.digitalpersona.com/Biometrics/SDK-Products/One-Touch-Software-Development-Kits-%28SDKs%29/). A problem may arise in that you will likely not be able to access the scanner from the browsers security context without the blessing of the user. Additionally, the Digital Persona drivers may require that you install extra software on the client's machine.

Answer (score 0):

You would need:

1. A fingerprint capturing device (something like 30 USD to a few hundred USD depending on the spec)
2. A fingerprint matching SDK (download one that is in the public domain [here](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm))

Then you write:

1. Client code that captures and submits fingerprint images.
2. Server code that receives a person's fingerprint image at registration, converts that into minutiae data, checks that quality of the image/minutiae to make sure the fingerprint minutiae is usable, then stores it in the DB.
3. Receives a person's fingerprint image at login, converts that into minutiae data and matches that with the fingerprint in the DB by calling the matching library. Usually you will get a matching score back, with which you can decide whether you consider it the same identity by using a threshold (`if score > threshold then authenticate`, etc.)

That's the basic idea. The link I provided should have all the libraries you need. Note also that you might need to process the image captured by the capturing device so that you can use it with the libraries.

Biometrics isn't easy. Even if you have the libraries, you can't just use them without careful planning/tuning etc. So it's not like you are good to go to build a production app. just because you have these libraries. It's quite different from say, using `Hibernate` as a library. So if you are just interested in quickly adding this functionality on your app., you should reconsider because it will take a lot of work to make this work. If you are prepared to understand how these libraries work, play around with image processing, learn about biometrics etc., then it might be fun :)

There are probably libraries out there that you can buy (probably together with the capturing hardware) which will make this process much easier, but they are very expensive.